# few questions on Clonezilla

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, clone, clonezilla

I'm trying to clone my windows xp installation.

1. If I back it up using Clonezilla and the my XP machine is infected by virus/spyware would I also be bringing the whole mess when I try to back it up.
2. Do I need the whole partition/ whole disk if I use an external hard drive to backup.
   Would the data be formatted on the partition that I choose?
3. And were also having rotating brown outs here. Would it destroy my current installation or the hardware that I use to backup in case there is a brownout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yup, it is a complete image of your drive. Warts and all.

2) The data will be saved as files in a folder on the destination USB drive

3) Not sure I understand the question. If you lose power while creating the clone image you'll want to start over. If you lose power while restoring the clone image you will **definitely** want to start over.